# Is it good practice having local variables starting with underscore?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

I'm just getting into Ruby and come from the Java and C/C++ environment.

While coding a first little project in Ruby, I somehow got used to let all local variables start with an underscore. I guess my main motivation for this was a better readability and distinction from method calls.

As in principle there are only three types of variables (`$global`, `@instance` and `local`), the vast majority of variables start with an underscore. I'm not really sure, whether this is good or bad. Besides, in a lot other languages, the underscore would be substituted to some other character.

Is there somehow a *best practice* concerning variable naming beside the usual *CamelCase* and/or *underscore separated*? What are the habits of the professional "rubyists"? Have I overlooked some general Ruby conventions, when I chose the leading underscore?

---

**edit**
Thanks to all answers and suggestions. It helped me a lot.

---

**Short Summary of Answers and Comments below**
*(for the short-on-time visitor)*

Leading underscores go with:

- method arguments: `def my_method(_my_arg)`
- block arguments: e.g. `my_array.each { |_x| puts _x}`

All other local variables without leading underscores, as programmers coming from e.g. [JavaScript might get confused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977083/588243) about intended behaviour of the variables.

For visual separation between variable names and method calls, forcing oneself to use  "`(`"  brackets "`)`" with *all* method calls might increase readability significantly.

Comment: What other languages do isn't really a concern, because every language has different coding styles. I sometimes use variables with leading underscores in block parameters, i.e. `{ |_a,_b| ... }` when I want to make them stand out, or it makes the code more readable. Readability translates to maintainability over time, so go with what flows in and out of your eyes and head the easiest.

Comment: @theTinman: Underscores with block arguments seems a reasonable way as well. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Torbjoern thanks for the short summary, very helpful

Comment: Jim Stewart's answer is the accepted answer within ruby for variables and it is written in style guides like AirBnB's https://github.com/airbnb/ruby#throwaway-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your idea. But if I was having trouble distinguishing local vars from method calls, I would probably just force myself to always use `()`'s on methods. (My team at work has discussed making this part of our coding standards).

```
a = thing # var
b = thing() # method
```

The possible advantage to this is readability to others. Someone may wonder at your leading _'s, but using `()`'s on all method calls should be clear to everyone.

Comment: Do you use the brackets only with method calls without arguments or with **all** method calls no matter how many arguments there are passed?

Comment: With **all** method calls. (I'm actually not that strict myself, but some people at work are pushing for it, and I think it could be helpful in cases like the above.)

Comment: But doesn't the whole code get's too crowded very soon? But this leads to another discussion about introducing white spaces, and there is not **the** one solution.

Comment: That wouldn't work with `super` because `super` and `super()` are two different things.

Comment: Using `()` to call a function is not a rubyism, it is in fact forbidden in some style guides like AirBnB's https://github.com/airbnb/ruby#no-args-parens

Answer (score 15):

Existing answers to this question are now a few years old, and conventions have changed. You should only ever use a leading underscore (`_some_param`), or a standalone underscore (`_`), to indicate that you don't care about the value. The [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) style linting tool will carp about a "useless assignment" if you assign a variable but don't use it, but it will ignore variables with a leading underscore. This allows you to expressly indicate that you don't care about the value and don't intend to use it.

Here's a somewhat-contrived example use-case in an RSpec context:

```
describe 'login' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, login: 'bob') }
  it 'must be unique' do
    _user1 = user
    user2 = User.new login: 'bob'
    expect(user2.valid?).to be_false
  end
end
```

Here we're indicating that our `user` helper has a side-effect and returns something, but we don't care about it. You could also just skip the assignment entirely, but seeing a bare `user` on a line by itself looks odd and doesn't reveal the intention as clearly:

```
describe 'login' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, login: 'bob') }
  it 'must be unique' do
    user
    user2 = User.new login: 'bob'
    expect(user2.valid?).to be_false
  end
end
```

Other scenarios include ignoring values in iterators, or overriding a method where you want to keep the original method signature but don't care about some of the values:

```
def greet(name, _title)
  puts "Hi, #{name}!"
end
```

Comment: The most common way you'll see this is via `Array` parallel assignment.  e.g. if a function "returns 3 values" (really an `Array` of length 3) and you aren't going to use the first variable, you would write:

`_, myvar2, myvar3 = three_arg_function`

or

`_myvar1, myvar2, myvar3 = three_arg_function`

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, underscore-prefixed variables in Ruby are much like underscore-prefixed variables in JavaScript: a "don't touch" flag. More specifically, they are used when the implementer is doing something that really is not supposed to be understood as a part of the object, or shouldn't be thought of as the conceptual interface of the object.

This is more clear in the JavaScript world, where somebody is emulating "private" by prefixing a variable with an underscore. They are encoding that there's part of the object that's under the hood and can be ignored when looking at the object from the outside.

In Ruby, I've only really seen this with things like a cache or a singleton instance - the kind of thing that should be invisible to consumers of your object. Non-underscored variables are things that people using your object might be interested to know are there.

In any case, they seem fairly rare, and I would avoid them unless you want to send a signal to the next guy that's coming along that there's some extra magic or voodoo happening.

As far as making a distinction for method calls, if you're worried that there can be confusion between a method and a local variable, I would call the method on `self` to clarify. For instance:

```
def foo
    ...
end

def some_method
    foo # method
    bar # variable
end
```

If this seems unclear for whatever reason, you can clarify with

```
def some_method
    self.foo
    bar
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But I guess, using `self.` for method calls is going to confuse myself. Isn't `def self.foo` a definition of a class (not instance) method? As I'm using such very rarely, a `self.` will catch my eye and makes me think I'm confronted with a class method definition.

Comment: Yes, it is, but the key is to understand the scoping of `self`. Remember, in Ruby, everything is an object - in, say, C++, there's no such thing as a class object, only instances that are built from a class definition. Practically, at runtime, there is no class, just a collection of methods around a common set of data. In ruby, even classes are instances. When you're defining the class, `self` is this _class_ instance, and when you're in a method, `self` is the _instance_ of that class. I know this is confusing - it's hard to explain...

Comment: I don't know, whether it's hard to explain. For me it's rather logical and consequent as it is done in Ruby. Anyway, thank's for trying elucidating it :)

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as how instance variables have the `@` sign in front of them, and global variables have the `$` sign in front of them already in ruby, it is probably unnecessary to put an underscore character in front of the variable names.  That being said, I don't think it is a bad practice necessarily.  If it helps you to read or write your code in Ruby, then you should use it.

I have sometimes seen Ruby code where an argument for an instance method on a class has an underscore in front of it.  Such as:

```
def my_method(_argument1)
  # do something
end
```

And I think that when you are dealing with a class that may have it's own attributes, like a model file in rails, for instance, this can be helpful so that you know you are dealing with a variable that has been passed into the method as opposed to one of the attributes that belongs to the class/model.

Comment: Using underscores only with method arguments, seems to be a good thing. Thank's for sharing this.

Comment: If your methods are so long that the parameter list is no longer visible on the screen, you shouldn't splatter them with underscores, you should refactor them to be smaller.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - If you read my description, I didn't say anything about length of methods or number of parameters, I simply said that it can be helpful when writing a class instance method to differentiate that these variables are arguments for the method as opposed to a method or attribute of the class itself.  Again, it's not necessary but can sometimes be helpful.